# HDFS thrift server returns content of local FS, not HDFS

Tags: php, hadoop, thrift, hdfs

I am accessing HDFS using thrift.

1. This is the expected(and right) content on HDFS.

   ```
   [hadoop@hdp-namenode-01 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /
   Found 3 items
   drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2012-04-26 14:07 /home
   drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2012-04-26 14:21 /tmp
   drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2012-04-26 14:20 /user
   ```
2. And then I start an HDFSThriftServer

   ```
   [hadoop@hdp-namenode-01 ~]$ jps
   17290 JobTracker
   16980 NameNode
   27289 Jps
   17190 SecondaryNameNode
   17511 RunJar
   25270 HadoopThriftServer
   ```
3. Try to access content through thrift in PHP.

```php
    $transport = new TSocket(HDFS_HOST, HDFS_PORT);
    $transport->setRecvTimeout(60000);
    $transport->setSendTimeout(60000);
    $protocol =new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
    $client = new ThriftHadoopFileSystemClient($protocol);
    logv("connect hdfs");
    $transport->open();
    logv("testing existent of `%s'", $remote_uri);
    $remote_path = new Pathname(array('pathname' => $remote_uri));
    $remote_file = null;
    try {
            $remote_file = $client->listStatus($remote_path);
    } catch(Exception $e) { }
    if (!$remote_file)
        loge("could not open `%s'", $remote_uri);
```

While `$remote_uri` is an absolute path. For `$remote_uri === '/non/existent'` or `'/user'`, etc., listStatus always fail. But if I change it to `'/tmp'`, I find that it lists the content of `'/tmp'` of the thrift server's local FS.

So the returned content is local FS on the thrift server instead of HDFS!
What's wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that the `HadoopThriftServer` is running in some local mode, whereby it's default FileSystem is local, not DFS. I'm not familiar with this product though, so don't know how you would fix this

Comment: There is no option to configure HDFS thrift server other than the port it listens on.

Comment: Dig into HadoopThriftServer for a while and find that FileSystem object is created with an empty Configuration object, then fs.default.name is default to file:///, not the configured HDFS.

Comment: OK, at last I add ${HADOOP_HOME}/conf to classpath and it's solved.