# Hadoop Hdfs DFSAdmin - Cannot initialize Cluster or hdfs points to file:/// not hdfs://

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I'm using hadoop DFSAdmin api to report the dead blocks for an hdfs backup utility.
[enter link description here](https://blog.woopi.org/wordpress/files/hadoop-2.6.0-javadoc/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/DFSAdmin.html)

But by invoking my jar in the env (included the hadoop jars in classpath)

```
java -classpath  "/usr/local/flytxt/hadoop:/usr/local/HBackup/conf:/usr/local/HBackup/lib/*:/usr/local/HBackup/hadoop-distcp-2.7.5.jar" -Djava.library.path="/usr/local/HBackup/lib/native"  -jar hdfs-br-dfsadmin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

fails returning:

```
report: FileSystem file:/// is not an HDFS file system
Usage: hdfs dfsadmin [-report] [-live] [-dead] [-decommissioning]
```

This is the code:

```
    String[] argv= {"-report", "-dead" };
    DFSAdmin.main(argv);
```

Tried this thread: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391226/hadoop-hdfs-points-to-file-not-hdfs)
but no help!

Comment: did core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml are in your classpath?

Comment: Yes all five xmls are there in /usr/local/flytxt/hadoop