# hdfs access over thrift - does HadoopThriftServer still exist?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, thrift

I have been trying to access hdfs without yarn etc. and since [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) advertises thrift support, I was under the impression, hdfs/hadoop comes with a (java) thrift server and you only have to define the client in the language of your choice (Haskell in my case).

I have not yet been successful and lots of the information out there seems to be outdated - for example I have not been able to procure an official thrift file for hdfs, the official link [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-APIs) is broken.

Looking deeper for the server side, I found old posts regarding hadoop-thriftfs-0.2 mentioning a separate thrift server startup, sometimes named HadoopThriftServer [here](https://sites.google.com/a/blamethecomputer.com/segfault/braindump/using-perl-and-thrift-to-access-hdfs) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331992/hdfs-thrift-server-returns-content-of-local-fs-not-hdfs).

I have not been able to determine the current state of such a server project (apart from a [shady, probably obsolete download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoopthriftfs0202appendjar.htm)). I could of course implement the thrift server myself using the java bindings, but since I am under the impression that should already be done I would rather not...
(Basis: spec from an [old github project](https://github.com/semk/HadoopFS/tree/master/hadoopfs))

Is the thrift support obsolete (maybe discarded in favor of the REST API)? Am I overlooking something obvious? What would be the proper way to use the hadoop file system without the rest of the infrastructure (in a language other than java)?

Notes: Most of the hadoop/thrift documentation/examples are for hbase etc., not plain hdfs. At the moment I am not interested in hbase, before adding another level to the stack, I would rather go a completely different way.
I am especially interested in hdfs functions needed for ensuring data locality your own way.

Comment: I started my own implementation: https://github.com/michaxm/hdfs-thrift-bindings - still, that code must already be out there ...